# CC BY-SA 3.0 attribution in Android app

Tags: android, api, licensing, wiktionary

I'm developing a mobile app that uses [Wiktionary API](http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php) for retrieving some articles from Wiktionary. This application is going to be commercial. I've read that Wiktionary materials are available under [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). Also I've read next statement in the Wiktionary Terms of Use:

> Please note that these licenses **do allow commercial uses** of your
>   contributions, as long as such uses are compliant with the terms.

So my question is: how exactly do I implement "CC BY-SA 3.0" license in my application? I mean: what (links, names or something else) and where (popups or menu items) should I put into my application to satisfy this license?

Comment: Please consult with qualified legal counsel for licensing questions, as that is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Please see: http://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Terms_of_use#7._Licensing_of_Content for a starter.

Comment: @Dmytro Have you implemented "CC BY -SA 3.0"? If yes then please guide me.

Comment: It's funny that I've just earned a "Notable Question" badge for this question, which was closed as an off-topic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there are non-commercial licenses on CC, for example, [Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported (CC BY-NC-SA 3.0)](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/), which has additional non-commercial restrictions. So, I think you are safe to use [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) materials commercially.

To implement it, you simply do as asked:

- Attribution: You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor (but not in any way that suggests that they endorse you or your use of the work).
- Share Alike: If you alter, transform, or build upon this work, you may distribute the resulting work only under the same or similar license to this one.

or more understandably, state

- where the material in you app is from (i.e. Wiktionary), and
- what license the material is shared in (i.e. CC BY-SA)

Comment: _"Share Alike: If you alter, transform, or build upon this work, you may distribute the resulting work only under the same or similar license to this one."_ Does that mean the entire app should be licensed under _"Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License"_ or just the included material within it?